# I am having trouble implementing game center with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on a productivity application in Xcode 7.2 with Swift 2. I am trying to implement game center to add a leaderboard.

When I try to use:

```
GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, {(error : NSError!) -> Void
```

command I have get the following error:

> "Cannot convert value of type '(NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type '((NSError?) -> Void)?'"

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? I am new to Xcode and Swift, and am looking for a semi-simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what the error message is telling you. Change `NSError!` to `NSError?`.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know it was that simple! As I said, I'm new to swift and Xcode.

Comment: @DALabs Don't forget to accept answers that best solve the issue in your question.